# Jquery draggable/sortable array only partially working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to create a sortable photo list, i tried all i had in mind with that Array that's generated by Draggable/Sortable but it doesn't work, i'm sure i'm using it in a wrong way, but it's curious that for original position and original position +1 (if you move the photo in the next position) it reports the position correctly, but in higher positions everything is messed.

**You can see here what i'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/sovidiu/6EvFJ/**

Try moving the first photo in the second position -> works
Try moving the first photo in the 3rd,4rd pos. -> doesn't work.

Comment: dude, I tried that fiddle and works perfect. I'm using chrome. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but having (imgOrder2.indexOf("1")+1) as the index makes more sense. "Picture 1 in pos: x" displays correctly now. I'm also not sure why you are adding the id "sortable" to the imgOrder2 array each time, so I removed that.

```
var imgOrder = '';

$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
    var imgOrder = new Array();

      imgOrder = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray').toString();
      imgOrder2 = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray');
      $('#ceva').text(imgOrder2);
      $('#p1').text(imgOrder2.indexOf("1")+1);
      $('#p2').text(imgOrder2.indexOf("2")+1);
      $('#p3').text(imgOrder2.indexOf("3")+1);
      $('#p4').text(imgOrder2.indexOf("4")+1);
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();


});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed that indexOf was the issue and works perfectly now! Thanks again!